# Determine the running time of an algorithm with two parameters

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have implemented an algorithm that uses two other algorithms for calculating the shortest path in a graph: Dijkstra and Bellman-Ford. Based on the time complexity of the these algorithms, I can calculate the running time of my implementation, which is easy giving the code.

Now, I want to experimentally verify my calculation. Specifically, I want to plot the running time as a function of the size of the input (I am following the method described [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/)). The problem is that I have two parameters - number of edges and number of vertices.

I have tried to fix one parameter and change the other, but this approach results in two plots - one for varying number of edges and the other for varying number of vertices.

This leads me to my question - how can I determine the order of growth based on two plots? In general, how can one experimentally determine the running time complexity of an algorithm that has more than one parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very difficult in general.

The usual way you would experimentally gauge the running time in the single variable case is, insert a counter that increments when your data structure does a fundamental (putatively `O(1)`) operation, then take data for many different input sizes, and plot it on a `log-log` plot. That is, `log T` vs. `log N`. If the running time is of the form `n^k` you should see a straight line of slope `k`, or something approaching this.  If the running time is like `T(n) = n^{k log n}` or something, then you should see a parabola. And if `T` is exponential in `n` you should still see exponential growth.

You can only hope to get information about the highest order term when you do this -- the low order terms get filtered out, in the sense of having less and less impact as `n` gets larger.

In the two variable case, you could try to do a similar approach -- essentially, take 3 dimensional data, do a `log-log-log` plot, and try to fit a plane to that.

However this will only really work if there's really only one leading term that dominates in most regimes.

Suppose my actual function is `T(n, m) = n^4 + n^3 * m^3 + m^4`.

When `m = O(1)`, then `T(n) = O(n^4)`.
When `n = O(1)`, then `T(n) = O(m^4)`.
When `n = m`, then `T(n) = O(n^6)`.

In each of these regimes, "slices" along the plane of possible `n`,`m` values, a different one of the terms is the dominant term.

So there's no way to determine the function just from taking some points with fixed `m`, and some points with fixed `n`. If you did that, you wouldn't get the right answer for `n = m` -- you wouldn't be able to discover "middle" leading terms like that.

I would recommend that the best way to predict asymptotic growth when you have lots of variables / complicated data structures, is with a pencil and piece of paper, and do traditional algorithmic analysis. Or possibly, a hybrid approach. Try to break the question of efficiency into different parts -- if you can split the question up into a sum or product of a few different functions, maybe some of them you can determine in the abstract, and some you can estimate experimentally.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily two input parameters is still easy to visualize in a 3D scatter plot (3rd dimension is the measured running time), and you can check if it looks like a plane (in log-log-log scale) or if it is curved. Naturally random variations in measurements plays a role here as well.

In Matlab I typically calculate a least-squares solution to two-variable function like this (just concatenates different powers and combinations of `x` and `y` horizontally, `.*` is an element-wise product):

```
x = log(parameter_x);
y = log(parameter_y);

% Find a least-squares fit
p = [x.^2, x.*y, y.^2, x, y, ones(length(x),1)] \ log(time)
```

Then this can be used to estimate running times for larger problem instances, ideally those would be confirmed experimentally to know that the fitted model works.

This approach works also for higher dimensions but gets tedious to generate, maybe there is a more general way to achieve that and this is just a work-around for my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to write my own explanation but it wouldn't be any better than [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/30036/can-a-big-oh-time-complexity-contain-more-than-one-variable).